# Not only client connections? Is "MongoDB Wire Protocol" also used for replication?

Tags: replication, mongodb, mongodb-3.2

It seems that [MongoDB Wire Protocol](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-wire-protocol/) is also used for replication. Not only client/driver connections. Is that true and what are the main differences between client/driver and replication traffic?

> The MongoDB Wire Protocol is a simple socket-based, request-response
>   style protocol. Clients communicate with the database server through a
>   regular TCP/IP socket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a protocol perspective, there is no difference. A really basic way to think of it is this (assuming you start a secondary that is reasonably up to date and is not performing an [initial sync](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-sync/)):

- Replication is a client connection from a secondary to the primary
- That is done using TCP/IP and with the MongoDB wire protocol being used over the top (unless you are using SSL, which would add that to the mix)
- The secondary creates a [tailable cursor](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/tailable-cursors/) and begins streaming the operations from [the Oplog](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-oplog/)
- The secondary applies these [idempotent](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/glossary/) operations to its data in order to reach the same state as the primary

Now, in reality things are more complicated than that but that gives you a good starting point. You still have to add in multi-threaded replication, replication chaining so that you can replicate from another secondary rather than the primary etc. These are advanced topics which I have given multi-hour whiteboard sessions on (when I worked in MongoDB) and beyond the scope of this answer, not to mention the fact that I am likely out of date with my information at this point.

If you would like to go deeper into how replication works, I recommend the [internals posts](https://www.kchodorow.com/blog/2010/10/12/replication-internals/) from Kristina Chodorow (though they are a little dated these days) as well as the various talks the MongoDB engineers have given on the topic (here is [one example](https://www.mongodb.com/presentations/replication-internals-life-write-0)).